# Filtering the data set that goes into a local cube

Tags: mdx

I would like to create local cubes which are already filtered by a dimension (in this case time).

```
   CREATE GLOBAL CUBE [My_lclc_Cube]
       Storage 'C:\LocalCube.cub'
       FROM [MainCube]
       (
               MEASURE [MainCube].[Count],

        MEASURE [MainCube].[Price],
        MEASURE [MainCube].[Stake],
        DIMENSION [MainCube].[Market],
        DIMENSION [Calendar Year].[Date] (

)
```

In a normal mdx query I would simply add 
`where ([Calendar Year].[Relative Day].&[-1]:[Calendar Year].[Relative Day].&`[-7])

Is this possible? The documentation is opaque.

Comment: is this `SSAS` syntax?

Comment: Yes. https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms145581%28v=sql.110%29.aspx

Comment: I cannot see anything in that definition allowing custom sets to be included in your expression.